# Combining multiple variables into one

Tags: python, variables

I am working on a program that uses many variables as effectively the programs 'memory' of events, and I have a way to combine some of the variables in order to make things look and act cleaner, using strings. I want to know any possible way to do this possible.

Example of what I mean

```
train_wheel_count = 6
train_car_count = 1
train_useless_info = 23
```

becomes one variable named train_info, where all the values are contained.

I'm just trying to weigh my options.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Python dictionary:

```py
train_info = {"Wheel Count": 6, "Car Count": 1, "Useless Info": 23}
```

See this for more: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp

A more complex but perhaps better way would be to use classes:

```py
class Train:
    def __init__(self, number_of_wheel, car_count, useless_info):
        self.number_of_wheel = number_of_wheel
        self.car_count = car_count
        self.useless_info = useless info

my_train = Train(6, 4, 23)
print(my_train.car_count)

my_second_train = Train(4, 2, 15)
```

You may want to look at https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp. This method is slightly more complex, but will help you get much more done in the future.

For example, say we add a variable called `is_operational`.

```py
class Train:
    def __init__(self, number_of_wheel, car_count, useless_info, is_operational=True):

        self.number_of_wheel = number_of_wheel
        self.car_count = car_count
        self.useless_info = useless info

        self.is_operational = is_operational

    def set_operational(is_operational):
        self.is_operational = is_operational
```

You can then say something like `my_train.set_operational(False)` or manipulate each 'Object' differently.

Comment: Can you nest multiple dictionaries in a class?

Comment: Yes, you could have a variable in the class called `self.data = {"key0": "value0", ...}` and you could access that too.

Comment: If this answer helped you, I would appreciate it if you accepted it :)

Comment: thanks again, this makes everything so much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with dictionaries ?

```
 train_info = {
   "train_wheel_count": 6,
   "train_car_count": 1,
   "train_useless_info": 23
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

a array is also a possible solution:

```
train_wheel_count = 6
train_car_count = 1
train_useless_info = 23

train_info = [train_wheel_count, train_car_count, train_useless_info]

print(train_info)
>[6, 1, 23]
```

Answer (score -2):

Use binary data.

Below is the answer to your question. Feel free to comment if it doesnt work! It may not work with numbers over 1000000, but still does it.

```
train_wheel_count = 6
train_car_count = 1
train_useless_info = 23

train_info = chr(train_wheel_count) + chr(train_car_count) + chr(train_useless_info)
```

Hope it does it!

is the output, all looks the same, but they are different unicode entities. To decode, loop over the chars in this string and use ord!